# Why is the word "Document" added in my .find() output?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

The output of a publish command Collection.find({}) in one meteor backend outputs:

```
[ Document {
    _id: 'fpYe5XepB9AfJM4PJ',
} ]
```

...whilst the same command in another outputs the document as just

```
[ {
    _id: 'fpYe5XepB9AfJM4PJ',
} ]
```

What is the meaning of the included "Document" element, and the functional difference between the two?

Comment: I found that the former "[ Document {" type is present in the meteor todo app, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the first element of the array is an instance of `Document` constructor. Some logging utilities like the Chrome console's logger show the type of an object for providing more information.

Here is a simple example of a constructor function:

```
> var Document = function(id) { this._id = id; };
> var instance = new Document('a-unique-id');
> console.log( instance );
< Document { _id: "a-unique-id" }
```

Logging a plain object:

```
> console.log( { _id: "a-unique-id" } );
< { _id: "a-unique-id" }
```